# Delete Local site collection term set

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, term-store, term-set

I had a user try to create a Local `Term Set` for a site collection, then pin term with children from our actual term store and I need to delete the Local Term Set for the site collection.

When I go to delete I get a message which sounds like it will delete the term from the actual term store and not just the local site collection

[image]

It is the 'Client' Term set that needs deleting from the site collection group, my question is, if I delete 'Client' will it delete the top highlighted 'Communities and local government' term set from our actual term store. I have searched for the answer but I cannot find anything that would help.

[image]

Hope this makes sense, any questions just ask.

Thanks

Comment: It won't delete the term from the source as we are reusing the existing terms . it'll only delete the term in the site collection level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is quite misleading. But that is not the case - Delete will only delete what is under the Term Set.

> This action deletes the term and its child terms. If this term is a source term that other locations reuse, it is put in the Orphaned Terms term set in the System group.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-manage-terms-in-a-term-set-549070a7-41c2-4210-9e9c-5fad22bd8748